# I keep getting an error when I try to install R via Homebrew on OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)

Tags: r, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

I am able to use my existing versions of R and RStudio just fine, but I cannot seem to sync the version I have in `/Applications` with the Terminal in El Capitan, which means I cannot use ESS in emacs.

```
shermmac:~ brandonsherman$ brew install R
==> Installing r from homebrew/homebrew-science
==> Using Homebrew-provided fortran compiler.
This may be changed by setting the FC environment variable.
==> Downloading http://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/R-3/R-3.2.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/r-3.2.2.tar.gz
==> Patching
patching file src/modules/lapack/vecLibg95c.c
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1 --with-libintl-
==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/brandonsherman/Library/Logs/Homebrew/r/02.make:
5: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'America/New_York'
clang -I../../../../include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/X11/include -I../../../include -I../../../../src/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c init.c -o init.o
clang -I../../../../include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/X11/include -I../../../include -I../../../../src/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c tcltk.c -o tcltk.o
clang -I../../../../include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/X11/include -I../../../include -I../../../../src/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c tcltk_unix.c -o tcltk_unix.o
making tcltk.d from tcltk.c
making init.d from init.c
making tcltk_unix.d from tcltk_unix.c
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L../../../../lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -o tcltk.so init.o tcltk.o tcltk_unix.o -L/usr/local/lib -ltcl8.6 -L/usr/local/lib -ltk8.6 -L/usr/X11/lib -lX11 -Wl,-weak-lXss -lXext -L../../../../lib -lR -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: library not found for -lX11
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[4]: *** [tcltk.so] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all] Error 1
make[2]: *** [R] Error 1
make[1]: *** [R] Error 1
make: *** [R] Error 1

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/homebrew):
  https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-science/issues

Warning:
```

Note that there is nothing after Warning:.

Comment: did you re-install command line tools?

Comment: No, but I updated XCode.

Comment: try also reinstalling the command line tools. i'd actually consider redoing all of homebrew post-upgrade. I just fresh-installed and did my best to recover what i needed vs deal with upgrade headaches from this OS update.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I just reinstalled command line tools for 10.10.  I have the same error message.

Answer (score 3):

I reinstalled Command Line Tools for 10.10 and rebooted.  I then installed R 3.2.2 via Homebrew as in the original question.  It gave me the following error regarding my gfortran compiler:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/gcc/5/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/gcc/5/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

`brew link gcc` got rid of this error.  R now works fine.

Comment: For some reason my homebrew files are linked with `gcc5`. Using `brew unlink gcc5` then `brew link gcc` works for me. Thanks!